# AVPlayer does not fire playbackBufferEmpty but does not play either

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayeritem

I use AVPlayer to play an audio livestream via internet. I like to recover playback if it was paused for longer than 1 minute.

I call `player.rate = 1.0` to resume. However if the stream was paused for >1 minute it does not play any more. I need to recreate AVPlayerItem in this case to make it work again.

So **how can I catch this case, so I know the playback did not recover?**

- I tried KVO on `player.rate`. It stays at `1.0` though. The player is not playing!
- I tried KVO on `currentItem.playbackBufferEmpty`. It is not called in this case though.
- `currentItem.status` does not switch to `.Failed`. It does not change at all.

The AVPlayer just seems to do nothing in this case. Any ideas?

I build a Playground code to demonstrate the issue:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

// keep it running forever so it plays audio
import XCPlayground
XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(true)

class AVPlayerTest {

    let player = AVPlayer()
    let streamurl = NSURL(string: "http://detektor.fm/stream/mp3/musik/")!

    func startTest() {
        let item = AVPlayerItem(URL: streamurl)
        player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(item)
        player.play()

        // give it some start time to build a buffer
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: #selector(timerTickedToPause), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    @objc func timerTickedToPause(timer: NSTimer) {
        player.pause()
        // pause now for some time. 90s is not enough.
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(120, target: self, selector: #selector(timerTickedToPlay), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    @objc func timerTickedToPlay(timer: NSTimer) {
        // try to resume playback

        print(player.rate)

        player.play()

        print(player.rate)

        // check in some seconds if it recovered
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: #selector(timerTickedCheck), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    @objc func timerTickedCheck(timer: NSTimer) {

        // it reports rate = 1.0 but is not playing here though!
        // there is no way to know for me it did not recover here!?
        print(player.rate)

        // recover by creating a new item works
        let item = AVPlayerItem(URL: streamurl)
        player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(item)
        player.play()
    }
}

let test = AVPlayerTest()
test.startTest()
```

Comment: This looks like the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617232/avplayer-cant-resume-after-paused-some-waiting

Comment: yes, exactly same, it works with fixed (non-livestream) videos, but on livestream it fails, I always re-initialize the player with item :/ If this question gets the solution please post it to mine as well.

Comment: I am perfectly ok to recreate `AVPlayerItem`. However I **need to know** if it failed.

Comment: Don't have time to try, but a suggestion, can you try player.pause() then player.play() and check after this if rate is 1

Comment: I did that in the debugger already. `player.pause()` and `player.play()` is the same as setting `player.rate` to `0` or `1` like Apple states in its documentation. After calling `player.rate = 1` it **does not play** but `rate` stays on `1`.

Comment: See my response here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38120330/4249825

Comment: A lot of this seems to be fixed by Apple in iOS 10.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Works for me using the iOS 10 avplayer.

Comment: What is working. What did you do for? I'am using iOS 10 and AVPlayer to stream a asset url, http://yp.shoutcast.com/sbin/tunein-station.pls?id=1577011 (for example) and I encounter exactly the same problem you described.

Answer (score 7):

Use the **timeControlStatus** of the AVPlayer instance which "indicates whether playback is currently in progress, paused indefinitely, or suspended while waiting for appropriate network conditions."

```
let status = player.timeControlStatus

switch status {
case .paused:
    print("timeControlStatus.paused")

case .playing:
    print("timeControlStatus.playing")

case .waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate:
    print("timeControlStatus.waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate")
    if let reason = player.reasonForWaitingToPlay {

        switch reason {
        case .evaluatingBufferingRate:
            print("reasonForWaitingToPlay.evaluatingBufferingRate")

        case .toMinimizeStalls:
            print("reasonForWaitingToPlay.toMinimizeStalls")

        case .noItemToPlay:
            print("reasonForWaitingToPlay.noItemToPlay")

        default:
            print("Unknown \(reason)")
        }
    }

}
```

I have the same issue but in my case, it occurs if I go into background while in the paused state. When I come back to forground .play() does not work. It gets stuck the waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate.evaluatingBufferingRate mode. 
At that point the AVPlayerItem.status instance is readToPlay.

At this time of writing whenever a startCommand is received I reset the AVplayer to be sure. But this seems clunky. Looking for a smoother solution.

Comment: didn't knew about timeControlStatus but seems to work like a charm, great answer!

Comment: I was forced to reload asset in AVPlayer because of the same reason. It must be something about stream properties though. I am playing audio streams from one provider - they play ok after interruption. Streams from another provider are never able to play after interruption (they are VAST ads, if anyone finds this info relevant).